# "Ambiguous use of" and constrained generic functions

Tags: swift

I have a set of functions that extract values from a dictionary, where the dictionary's value type is `Any` (it comes from JSON data, and I don't have control over the value types):

```
func get<T>(_ dict: [String: Any], key: String) throws -> T {
    // cast the value for the key to a T, and return
}

func get<T: RawRepresentable>(_ dict: [String: Any], key: String) throws -> T {
    // cast the value for the key to a T.RawValue, init a T, and return
}
```

This works fine. The first function can cast a value of a scalar type and return it, while the second can convert a raw value for an `enum` type into the higher-level Swift type.

If I add a third variant, the compiler becomes unhappy and I get a lot of "ambiguous use of" errors, flagging all three functions as candidates:

```
func get<T: RawRepresentable>(_ dict: [String: Any], key: String) throws -> T where T.RawValue == Double {
    // try to extract the value as an Double, init a T, and return
    // if that fails, extract as an Int, cast to a Double, init a T, and return
}
```

The idea with this function is that a double value might appear without its decimal, and actually be an `Int` in the dictionary, but it needs to be a `Double` in strongly-typed Swift-land.

Why is the compiler able to resolve the ambiguity *without* the third variant, but considers all three as equally valid candidates when it exists?

Edit: here is a playground that illustrates the problem.

```
enum E: Error {
    case error
}

func get<T>(_ dict: [String: Any], key: String) throws -> T {
    guard let value = dict[key] as? T else { throw E.error }
    return value
}

func get<T: RawRepresentable>(_ dict: [String: Any], key: String) throws -> T {
    guard let rawValue = dict[key] as? T.RawValue else { throw E.error }
    return T(rawValue: rawValue)!
}

func get<T: RawRepresentable>(_ dict: [String: Any], key: String) throws -> T where T.RawValue == Double {
    if let doubleValue = dict[key] as? Double {
        return T(rawValue: doubleValue)!
    } else if let intValue = dict[key] as? Int {
        return T(rawValue: Double(intValue))!
    }

    throw E.error
}

struct Wrapped: RawRepresentable {
    typealias RawValue = Double

    var rawValue: Double

    init?(rawValue: Double) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }
}

let dict: [String: Any] = ["int": 1, "double": 1.1]
let int: Int = try! get(dict, key: "int")
let double: Double = try! get(dict, key: "double")
let wrapped: Wrapped = try! get(dict, key: "int")
```

This produces a compile error (ambiguous use of `get(_:key:)`). Commenting out the third specialization of `get<T>` resolves the compiler error, but results in a runtime error because the integer value of the key `int` can't be cast using `as?` into a `Double`. Changing the key to `double` resolves that, but doesn't address the problem I was trying to solve.

I should note that this is now an academic question for me, since I've changed my parsing approach to use `Codable` and it handles parsing both floating point and integer values into `Float`/`Double` types in Swift.

Comment: I feel like the implementation of third method is a Bir flawed. You seem to assume that if the value isn't a double, then it must be an `Int`. It could be an `UInt` or a `Float` as well couldn't it?

Comment: This is a simplified case, but probably accurate for JSON. Text parsers will likely always treat "0.0" as a `Double`, rather than attempt to determine if the value could also be represented as a `Float` without losing precision. The same is true for `Int` vs. `UInt`.

Comment: OK I've deleted my answer because your example compiles for me (to the extent that it can be made compileable by tweaking obvious stuff like returning values). Perhaps you could add some more detail to make the example reproducible?